# PIL IndexError: image index out of range

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a chromakey program in Python. My test program is supposed to determine green colors in an image. If it finds green, it sets a certain value to True. The test image is a 4x4 image with no transparency.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

green_num = False
testpic = Image.open("test.png")
width, height = testpic.size
pix = testpic.load()


def coloradd():
    global colorlist
    colorlist = 0
    if green_value/(2/3) < red_value or blue_value:
        colorlist += 1


def colorscan():
    current_x = 0
    current_y = 0
    while current_y <= height:
        global red_value, green_value, blue_value
        red_value, green_value, blue_value, transparency = pix[current_x, current_y]
        coloradd()
        current_x += 1
        if current_x < width:
            current_y += 1


colorscan()
print(colorlist)
```

So far, I've continually run into this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shawnmcgp/PycharmProjects/untitled/chromakey.py", line 29, in <module>
    colorscan()
  File "C:/Users/shawnmcgp/PycharmProjects/untitled/chromakey.py", line 22, in colorscan
    red_value, green_value, blue_value, transparency = pix[current_x, current_y]
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this so far?

Comment: `current_y <= height` probably should be `<`. Your `y` coordinates are numbered 0-3 which is one less than the height of 4, so an index equal to the height is invalid. There are other problems, such as `if green_value/(2/3) < red_value or blue_value`, which will always be truthy whenever `blue_value` is not zero.

Comment: So far, I've replaced the multiple variable assigning with simply red_value, and edited all that entailed that, as well as trying a different, smaller picture, as my initial image was much larger.

Comment: It seems to run when I manually assign the tuple. I'll have to mess with it a bit more. Thanks.